# How can I get JSDoc to mark my param as a jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsdoc

I'm attempting to thoroughly comment my JavaScript and I'm using JSDoc.  I have a function that consumes a jQuery object and I'd like to mark the parameter as such.

Currently, I have this:

```
/**
 * Initializes a login object.
 * @param formEl {JQuery} The login form element on the page.
 */
var login = function(formEl){ ... }
```

But JSDoc doesn't recognize (or properly format) "JQuery" as a variable type.  Any help?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

According to http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/TagParam it should be

Param type before param name.

```
/**
 * Initializes a login object.
 * @param {jQuery} formEl The login form element on the page.
 */
var login = function(formEl){ ... }
```

Comment: That did it.  I figured it had to be something simple... Thanks!

Comment: And typically (at least in the code I've seen) the type is `jQuery` to match the name of the exported global variable.

Comment: As a convention, it is helpful to prefix JQuery objects with a `$`. That way everyone knows that `$formEl` is a JQuery reference to the element.

Comment: `@param {JQuery}` should be `@param {jQuery}`, with a lowercase j.

Comment: @LoopDuplicate VSCode tells me `jQuery` is the object behind `$`, used to select elements. `JQuery` on the other hand, is the element set object returned by `$(...)`.

Comment: @RedClover indeed it does... strange, is this intended, or a bug? I find it hard to write it with the uppercase `j`, as I always used it with the lower-case one.

Comment: @user5147563. You are right, JQuery is the jQuery object and the answer here should be changed to JQuery with a capital J IMO.