# What's the correct way to document a jQuery parameter type with JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsdoc

I'm trying to document my program with the JSDoc syntax for myself and the people that will have to look at my code. I'm also trying to improve my skills.

For a parameter of the jQuery type, I'm a little puzzled. I know that's an object, but it's fairly common in my program, so I think I should first declare a typedef for the jQuery type, then use it as my parameter type. So I ask, would it be the correct way to do it?

```
/**
 * DOM object referenced by jQuery
 * @typedef {jQuery} $jQueryDomObject
 */

/**
* SOAP call that does ...
*
* @param {string} code Some desc ...
* @param {callback} fnctVa Some desc ...
* @param {$jQueryDomObject} $attrib Input field that ...
*/
myfunction = function (code, fnctVa, $attrib) {};
```

I also found on SO this question, somewhat similar:
[How can I get JSDoc to mark my param as a jQuery object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610979/how-can-i-get-jsdoc-to-mark-my-param-as-a-jquery-object)

Comment: The correct thing is not making a SOAP call using a jQ object and to separepate concerns. Just saying. Interesting question nonetheless.

Comment: Ok I'll look into this. Whould you suggest a pattern instead ?

Comment: Separation of concerns is a principle and not a pattern. The idea in this case (it's applicable to more than GUI) is that your presentation logic and business logic should not be mixed like that. Some common design patterns that address the issue are mediator, observer and event emitter. Some architectural patterns that address the issue are MVC, MVVM and MVP.

Comment: Thanks for the architecture tip... ok so the GUI does not talk to the data directly and vice versa. Got it.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeMartin, I've done much the same documenting legacy code that I didn't have a hand in writing.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For a parameter that is a jQuery object, I often just do:

```
@param {jQuery} foo
```

And do not further define what jQuery is. It is known well enough. However, if you want, you can do this with jsdoc 3:

```
/**
 * jQuery object
 * @external jQuery
 * @see {@link http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/}
 */

/**
 * SOAP call that does ...
 *
 * @param {string} code Some desc ...
 * @param {callback} fnctVa Some desc ...
 * @param {external:jQuery} $attrib Input field that ...
 */
var myfunction = function (code, fnctVa, $attrib) {};
```

Answer (score 5):

I also saw on [github/js3doc](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/415):

```
@param {jQuery object} obj The jQuery object you're looking for.
```

or [github/js3doc](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/495)

```
@param {module:jquery} jquery Some desc...
```